# class sf::RenderWindow' has no member named 'clear'

Tags: c++, libraries, sfml

I've spent at least 5 hours trying to get the sfml library to work with my QT-creator ide. I have followed this tutorial https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Compile-and-Link-SFML-with-Qt-Creator but still no luck. 

I continuously get the error that members of classes don't exist after building simple code. I can make instances of the classes, but I get multiple errors when trying to use 

members of the objects created. I have tried looking up library related issues, sfml issues, but I don't think I'm looking for the correct problem.

This works and displays a window that will never close until forcing the program to quit:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    //sf::CircleShape shape(100.f );
    //shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (true)//window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        /*while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }*/

        //window.clear();
        //window.draw(shape);
        //window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I remove one comment an error pops up. I can't figure out for the life of me what's happening.

Thanks in advance.

**Extra Info**

**Os:**

Ubuntu 12.10 Live (installed to hard drive)

**Project File**


*I'm sure this is incorrect*

```
TEMPLATE = app

#CONFIG += console

CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -L"/home/user/Projects/SFML/lib"

CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

INCLUDEPATH += "/home/user/Projects/SFML/include"

DEPENDPATH += "/home/user/Projects/SFML/include"
```

**Errors:**
 

 *I'll post the compile output*

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:6:5: error: 'CircleShape' is not a member of 'sf'

main.cpp:6:21: error: expected ';' before 'shape'

main.cpp:7:5: error: 'shape' was not declared in this scope

main.cpp:12:23: error: 'class sf::RenderWindow' has no member named 'pollEvent'

main.cpp:14:23: error: 'class sf::Event' has no member named 'type'

main.cpp:15:24: error: 'class sf::RenderWindow' has no member named 'close'

main.cpp:18:16: error: 'class sf::RenderWindow' has no member named 'clear'

main.cpp:19:16: error: 'class sf::RenderWindow' has no member named 'draw'

main.cpp:20:16: error: 'class sf::RenderWindow' has no member named 'display'

16:25:10: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.

Error while building project sfmlTest (target: Desktop)

When executing build step 'Make'
```

**Executed Path**

```
make: Leaving directory `/home/username/Documents/Projects/c++/Sfml/sfmlTest-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release'
```

**Compiler Used:**

I believe the Gnu Compiler, G ++

Comment: Can you provide more information, especially an exact example of an error, the OS and compiler you're using and how you've setup your project exactly?

Comment: @Lukas -- I'll provide everything in a more neatly and orderly fashion at the bottom. I did however, provide everything besides the OS.

Comment: An error usually holds more than just the text, it has numbers to indicate where exactly the issue is raised. Qt Creator is an IDE that can use a lot of different compilers, so you need to be specific. And you just said you "followed" the tutorial, which does not exclude changes to the project file, which in turn can generate the error.

Comment: @Lukas Okay, I will provide you with the entire error message. Did you want the entire error list, or the message that was repeated? Also I will update the compiler used and changes done to the project file before the end of today. I did get the chance to update the Os though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lukas All info added.

Comment: According to [this manual](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1CircleShape.php) `CircleShape` is in `CircleShape.hpp` Is `Graphics.hpp` documented to include `CircleShape.hpp`. If not, why do you expect this to work?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I expected it to work because I got this source code as a test to see if sfml would work off a page: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-linux.php

Comment: @ta.speot.is the whole purpose of `Graphics.hpp` is to include all the headers of the graphics module that includes `CircleShape.hpp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but since you're on Ubuntu it's very likely that instead of compiling SFML yourself, you just called `apt-get install sfml-dev` which in turn will install SFML 1.6 and not SFML 2.x. In SFML 1.6 the naming convention was CamelCase and was changed for SFML 2.0 to camelCase.

Since you want and should use SFML 2.x, you need to either use the [unofficial package](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=11338.0) from the SFML forum or simply compile SFML yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what the problem. I ended up using these 4 lines of code and I got a basic circle shape to be rendered on screen.:
apt-add-repository ppa:sonkun/sfml-stable # for stable versions
apt-add-repository ppa:sonkun/sfml-development # for development versions
apt-get update
apt-get install libsfml